# Not able to publish shiny app

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am trying publishing shiny app (app.R) from rstudio-server to rstudio-connect which is using 3 different packages, mentioned below, which are available in my local repository. Packages downloaded from: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ to local repository with .tar.gz extension.

library(shiny)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(dplyr)

While deploying, I am receiving below error,

Preparing to deploy application...Warning: namespace ‘RevoScaleR’ is 
   not available and has been replaced by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘’
   Warning: namespace ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available and has been replaced
   by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘’
   Warning: namespace ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available and has been replaced
   by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘’
   DONE

Uploading bundle for application: 62...Error: Unable to retrieve package 
   records for the following packages:
   - 'stringi'
   In addition: Warning message:
   error reading the file 
   Execution halted

I tried to get packages from different places but still get same error messages.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `require` instead of `library`.